# Confusion about definition of statistical model

Tags: probability-theory, manifolds, information-theory, geometric-probability, information-geometry

Let $X$ be a sample space and define a probability distribution function $p:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x)\geq 0$ and $\int p(x)dx=1$,let $S$ be a family of probability distributions on $X$ ,suppose that each element of $S$ ,may be parametrized using n real-valued variables $[\xi^1,....,\xi^n]$ so that
$$S=\{p_{\xi}=p(x;\xi):\xi=[\xi^1,...,\xi^n]\in E\}$$ where $E\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$,we call such $S$ an n-dimensional statistical manifold.

let supp(p)=$\{x:p(x)>0\}$.Letting $X$ be redefined as supp(p),this is equivalent to assuming that $p(x;\xi)>0$ holds for all $\xi\in E$ and for all $x\in X$.This means that $S$ is a subset of $$P(X)=\{p:X\to\mathbb{R}:p(x)>0(\forall x \in X),\int p(x)dx=1\}$$

My question is how we are saying $S$ is a subset of $P(X)$. and what will be $S$ if we choose $X$ as supp(p)?

Also, the author says that when $X$ is a finite set we may consider $P(X)$ itself to be a statistical model which forms a $(|X|-1)$ dimensional manifold $(|X|$ denotes the cardinality of $X$).In this, we can consider $S$ is a submanifold of $P(X)$. How $S$ is a submanifold of $P(X)$ and what will happen if we have  $X$ as an infinite set.

Comment: I think its said a subset because $p>0$, however in general if $p\in S$ then $p\geqslant 0$

Comment: What difficulty do you have seeing that $S$ is a subset of $P(X)$?  What part of the definition of $P(X)$ do you think an element of $S$ does not have to satisfy?

Comment: if $S$ we have $p_(x;{\xi})$ suppose if I choose $p(x;\xi)=0$ since we have that $p(x;\xi)\geq 0$ so it is not it $P(X)$

Comment: @jeniffer, note that  $S$  is "a family of probability distributions", so $p(x;\xi) =0$ for all $x$ does not integrate 1 and, therefore, does not belongs to $S$.

Comment: @RenatoFernandes okay ,then how we are saying that $S$ is a subset of $P(X)$ can you explain??

Comment: $P(X)$ is the set of all functions $p$ that are positive for all $x \in X$  and integrates $1$. When we take $X$ as $supp(p)$, for all $p \in S$, $p(x)$ is positive and $p$ integrates $1$ (because it is a probability distribution). In that way, every $p \in S$ satisfies the conditions in the definition of $P(X)$.

Comment: @RenatoFernandes thanks, now I got it. One more thing as you can see in the question it is said that $P(X)$ is a statistical manifold of dimension $(|X|-1)$ and $S$ is a submanifold of $P(X)$, can you explain this, please. That will be great help ,thanks.